# mysql views my query output i need different manner

Tags: mysql

This is my query

```
Select Count(Case When campaign_pid != 0 Then 1 End) As Email,
  Count(Case When sms_pid != 0 Then 1 End) As Sms,
  Count(Case When survey_pid != 0 Then 1 End) As Survey
From tablename
```

---

Please help me
This is my query output

```
Email   Sms     Survey    
21     1       4
```

---

i need output like this

```
 name    value  
 Email   21  
 Sms     1   
 Survey  4
```

---

Please tell me how to get like above optput

Comment: Please provide table structure. btw u can use `UNION` to get expected result

Comment: campaign_pid  int(11)
 sms_pid  int(11)
 survey_pid  int(11)

Comment: I done know much UNION concept Please send me the query

Comment: Don't mistake me i am not understand Teh Codez means what

Answer (score 0):

TRY

```
SELECT COUNT(Case WHEN campaign_pid != 0 THEN 1 END) AS Email FROM tablename
UNION
SELECT COUNT(Case WHEN sms_pid != 0 THEN 1 END) As Sms FROM tablename
UNION
SELECT COUNT(Case WHEN survey_pid != 0 THEN 1 END) As Survey FROM tablename
```

[Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html)

Comment: Output came like this
Email
21
1
4
i need output like this

 name    value  
 Email   21  
 Sms     1   
 Survey  4

Comment: @Mohan if u get data already then u can manipulate with PHP whatever u want, why u want it from MYSQL??

Comment: I need query provide what ever i want 
I want to give input as query to software it provide output to me so only

Comment: I am going to apply this for chart x,y axis if three column means how to apply