# my sql sum the count values

Tags: mysql

```
Select Count(Case When an_user_plan.campaign_pid != 0 Then 1 End) As Email,
  Count(Case When an_user_plan.sms_pid != 0 Then 1 End) As Sms,
  Count(Case When an_user_plan.survey_pid != 0 Then 1 End) As Survey,
  sum(Email,Sms,Survey)as total
From an_user_plan
```

This `sum(Email,Sms,Survey)as total` have error how to sum the three values
I want total as addition of three count vlaues
how to do Please help me

Comment: Post the error message as well

Comment: [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415556/mysql-views-my-query-output-i-need-different-manner) by same user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(campaign_pid != 0 +
           sms_pid != 0 +
           survey_pid != 0) AS total, ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select Count(Case When an_user_plan.campaign_pid != 0 Then 1 End) +
  Count(Case When an_user_plan.sms_pid != 0 Then 1 End) +
  Count(Case When an_user_plan.survey_pid != 0 Then 1 End) as total
From an_user_plan
```

Answer (score 0):

While you have no GROUP BY clause, you could use variables -

```
SELECT @c1:=Count(...), @c2:=Count(...), @c1 + @c2 FROM table
```

Otherwise you can use a subquery -

```
SELECT c1, c2, c1 + c2 FROM (
  SELECT Count(...) c1, Count(...) c2 FROM table) t
```